# How to get code that uses x86intrin.h to run on MAC

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I am trying to get the code for [clhash](https://github.com/lemire/clhash/blob/master/include/clhash.h) to run on MacOS Big Sur. The problem is that it uses `#include <x86intrin.h>`, which leads to many error messages like:

```
In file included from /Users/myusername/Scripts/projectname/clhash.c:5:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/x86intrin.h:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/immintrin.h:17:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I understand this has something to do with apple not using Intel processors. I am using the CLion environment, which uses CMakeLists for linker stuff. How can I fix this error?

Comment: The linked header doesn't appear to use any intrinsics, please show a [mre]

Comment: The problem is that `x86` indicates that it's code specifically for Intel and compatible processors. There's no way to use x86 code on a non-x86 processor, as the code is **specific to x86 processors**. So the answer to the question you've asked is *You can't*. @AlanBirtles may be right, though, and there's something in your code that is requiring that header that should not be, so you actually don't have that issue at all.

Comment: Your error message is actually for [clhash.c](https://github.com/lemire/clhash/blob/master/src/clhash.c) which does x86-specific non-portable stuff and there is no reasonable way to get it to work on a different architecture. As it says in the readme "And, yes, this means that CLHash is not portable hardware-wise.".

Comment: That is good to know. Thank you very much!